# Pattern Matching Multiple Word Patterns

Tags: regex

I'm hoping someone can help with some regular expression. I'm trying find instances where two patterns exist in a string (I think I'm saying that right).

Here is my test string:

```
{"eventid": 2121, "username":"FRED", "starttime": "1550243080", "newprocessname": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\wbem\\WmiPrvSE.exe", "parentprocessname": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\svchost.exe"}
```

I want to be able to search based on one or more criteria. The problem I have is when multiple criteria is provided. For example, the following seems to match if username is good or newprocessname is good whereas I want it to match only if both are good.

```
("username"\s*:\s*"(.*?)FRED(.*?)")|("newprocessname"\s*:\s*"(.*?)WINDOWS(.*?)")
```

I think my patterns are right, but how do I return a result only if both patterns match?

I hope I'm explaining this correct???

Thank you!

Jon

Comment: Sounds like a job for a JSON parser, not regex

Comment: I don't have the option of using a JSON parser, I need to string match it and only have the ability to regular expression match it :o(

Comment: You can do something like this https://regex101.com/r/MGPDkd/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a regex library that supports lookaheads you can use this regex:

```
^(?=.*"username"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)FRED([^"]*)")(?=.*"newprocessname"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)WINDOWS([^"]*)")
```

It looks for both the `username` and `newprocessname` tags at the same time (as the lookaheads don't consume any characters). Note that you need to change `.*?` in your regex to `[^"]*` otherwise you can match text further into the string than the actual value associated with the tag name.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OzpGk4/4/)